# Sensible way to keep data consistent primary/standby in postgres after primary vm revert

Tags: postgresql

Lets say that I create a primary/secondary postgres nodes using wal streams and pg_basebackup.

Create a snapshot on vm level of primary node.

Insert some random data that is synced to secondary as it should.
Revert primary back to snapshot on vm level.

Data on secondary is still present, as it should. WAL streaming on secondary is throwing errors - as it should.

But writing on primary is still possible as it knows nothing about previous state.
This will lead into very interesting state where some data on one node is correct, some is missing on one node and some is missing on another.

Is there a (nice) way to make primary aware that it has booted up into a previous state and standby is ahead of its timeline and deny any writing operations ?

Patroni cluster would be one option, but any options with postgres itself ?

best regards.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that solution is called “[synchronous replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-STANDBY-NAMES)”. If you put the `application_name` of the replication connection into `synchronous_standby_names`, the primary will block further data modifications.

Note that this is an academic question, as machines are not wont to jump into the past.

Comment: That's a good idea and while it has some drawbacks when secondary fails, it at least would keep data consistent. thanks :)